# Can someone check if my proof is correct?

Tags: surfaces, surface-integrals

I was working a tutorial and it had this proof listed below.  It says that *S* is a closed surface and *H* is a region
$$\int_S \frac{\textbf{r.n}}{r^2} dS\, = \int_H \frac{dH}{r^2} \,$$

My approach towards this question was that **r** = x**i** +y**j** + z**k** then if we try to find **n** it is equal to

$$\frac{grad{\phi}}{\mid grad{\phi}\mid} = \frac{(1,1,1)}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Therefore if we open *dS*, we would end up with the following

$$\int_{S'} \frac{\textbf{r.n}}{{r^2}}\frac{{dS'}}{{\textbf{n.k}}} \,$$

If we take **k** to be equal to (0,0,1), we would end up with the following equation,

$$\int_{S'} \frac{{\textbf{r}}.(1,1,1)}{{r^2}}\frac{{dS'}}{{1}} \,$$

Then **r** could be changed to (x,y,z)

$$\int_{S'} \frac{{(x,y,z)}.(1,1,1)}{{r^2}}dS' \,$$

Therefore

$$\int_{S'} \frac{{(x,y,z)}}{{r^2}}dS' \,$$

Then changing for region H

$$\iiint_H \frac{{(x,y,z)}}{{r^2}}dxdydz \,$$

is equal to

$$\int_{H} \frac{{dH}}{{r^2}} \,$$

Can somebody please check if my approach is correct?

Comment: Proof-verification tag is to be used when you provide a proof of something.

Answer (score 0):

### Hint

> $$\nabla\cdot\left({\hat{r}\over r}\right) = {1\over r^2}$$

Comment: Why would you take the divergence in this case?

Comment: Using the divergence theorem gives a trivial proof for the problem